# Query to calculate difference of one row based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with following sample data:

```
  ID   Code1   Code2 Amount
  -------------------------
   1     A       0    1500  
   1     0       B    1500  
   1     0       B     200  
   1     A       0     300
```

I want to check difference of sum of code1 and code2 is same or not. For this Code1 Sum is (1500+300) and code2 is (1500+200) and difference is 100

Please share the code

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(decode(code1, '0', 0, amount) - decode(code2, '0', 0, amount))
from your_table
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct, leaving some explanation would improve this question in a long run.

Answer (score 0):

You could try conditional `SUM` with `CASE` . It is important to include zero within quotes while comparing, since your columns `code1,code2` are character types .

```
SELECT   SUM (CASE WHEN code1 != '0' THEN amount ELSE 0 END)
       - SUM (CASE WHEN code2 != '0' THEN amount ELSE 0 END)
          diff
  FROM yourtable;
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct, leaving some explanation would improve this question in a long run.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  select case when code1='A' than sum(Amount) else 0 [Sum1] end,
      case when code2='B' than sum(Amount) else 0 [Sum2] end,
      case when [Sum1]=[S2] 'Same' else "Not Same' end
      from [Table_name];
```